# Synchronising data tables between websites

Tags: php, mysql

OK so I have a data table on one site full of ip addresses. I have another site with the same data table, and every week I'd like to sync from site a to site b

So I was thinking of getting the data by getting site b to do a file_get_contents() and call a url on site a, which runs a query and outputs the data by print_r

Is this the best way to do it or is there another way ?

Site B does

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://sitea.com/?data=synch');

$data = json_decode($json);

var_dump($data);
```

Site A does this when that URL is called

```
$db = $this->getConnection();       

$q = "SELECT * FROM data";

$this->_data = $db->recordset( $q );

return json_encode($this->_data);
```

When I try and get the data at the other end, I can't get it to become an array ?

var_dump($data) just gives me a null?

Here's what I get if I do var_dump($data) on site B

[{"ipID":"1","countryID":"13","beginIP":"1.0.0.0","endIP":"1.0.0.255","netMask":"24","beginIPNum":"16777216","endIPNum":"16777471"},{"ipID":"2","countryID":"44","beginIP":"1.0.1.0","endIP":"1.0.1.255","netMask":"24","beginIPNum":"16777472","endIPNum":"16777727"},{"ipID":"3","countryID":"44","beginIP":"1.0.2.0","endIP":"1.0.3.255","netMask":"23","beginIPNum":"16777728","endIPNum":"16778239"},{"ipID":"4","countryID":"13","beginIP":"1.0.4.0","endIP":"1.0.7.255","netMask":"22","beginIPNum":"16778240","endIPNum":"16779263"},{"ipID":"5","countryID":"44","beginIP":"1.0.8.0","endIP":"1.0.15.255","netMask":"21","beginIPNum":"16779264","endIPNum":"16781311"},{"ipID":"6","countryID":"107","beginIP":"1.0.16.0","endIP":"1.0.31.255","netMask":"20","beginIPNum":"16781312","endIPNum":"16785407"},{"ipID":"7","countryID":"44","beginIP":"1.0.32.0","endIP":"1.0.63.255","netMask":"19","beginIPNum":"16785408","endIPNum":"16793599"},{"ipID":"8","countryID":"107","beginIP":"1.0.64.0","endIP":"1.0.127.255","netMask":"18","beginIPNum":"16793600","endIPNum":"16809983"},{"ipID":"9","countryID":"211","beginIP":"1.0.128.0","endIP":"1.0.255.255","netMask":"17","beginIPNum":"16809984","endIPNum":"16842751"},{"ipID":"10","countryID":"44","beginIP":"1.1.0.0","endIP":"1.1.0.255","netMask":"24","beginIPNum":"16842752","endIPNum":"16843007"}]

I've validated it at JSONLint

IF i do $ipRecords = json_decode($data); and then var_dump($ipRecords); I get Null???

Comment: I wouldn't print_r the data as that is a pain to reverse on the B end. Use serialize and unserialize or json_en/decode.

Comment: I can't seem to get json_encode to work... editing questionwith my code

Comment: Can you verify that the `return json_encode($this->_data);` returns something useful?

Comment: yes, here is what I get back if I var_dump($data) on siteB (See question edit_

Comment: `IF i do $ipRecords = json_decode($data); and then var_dump($ipRecords); I get Null???`

Don't you mean `$ipRecords = json_decode($json)`?

Comment: That's really strange, because when I take that JSON of yours, json_decode it, then var_dump it, I don't have any issue.

Comment: yep that's what's puzzling us !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43344/discussion-between-rich-and-floris)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved in chat. Turned out site A was not just outputting the encoded JSON string, so site B needed a way to return just the JSON string from the file_get_contents call.

Solution presented:

On site A:

```
$db = $this->getConnection();       

$q = "SELECT * FROM data";

$this->_data = $db->recordset( $q );

return "@JSON_OUTPUT@". json_encode($this->_data) ."@JSON_OUTPUT@";
```

On site B:

```
$json = explode("@JSON_OUTPUT@", file_get_contents('http://sitea.com/?data=synch'));

$data = json_decode($json[1]);

var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have control over both site's ? or is it just web based ?
if you have control over both sites, make a **[mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)** and pass it (saver). guess its way easyer to work with. and you could run a cronjob to handle this so you wont have to mind anything after setting this up.

you should have a look at this to: **[Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)**

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of both servers replication would work as well.  Then you dont have to deal with it the server will do it all for you.